How to use 'Siri Voice 4' in terminal `say` command?
It complains voice not found
say -v "Siri Voice 4" hi
Voice `Siri Voice 4' not found.

Yet I have it in UI available and installed and used by default

But it's missing in the list of voices available in terminal
say -v '?' | grep en_
Alex                en_US    # Most people recognize me by my voice.
Ava                 en_US    # Hello, my name is Ava. I am an American-English voice.
Daniel              en_GB    # Hello, my name is Daniel. I am a British-English voice.
Fred                en_US    # I sure like being inside this fancy computer
Karen               en_AU    # Hello, my name is Karen. I am an Australian-English voice.
Moira               en_IE    # Hello, my name is Moira. I am an Irish-English voice.
Rishi               en_IN    # Hello, my name is Rishi. I am an Indian-English voice.
Samantha            en_US    # Hello, my name is Samantha. I am an American-English voice.
Tessa               en_ZA    # Hello, my name is Tessa. I am a South African-English voice.
Veena               en_IN    # Hello, my name is Veena. I am an Indian-English voice.
Victoria            en_US    # Isn't it nice to have a computer that will talk to you?

Mac OS Monterey 12.7.4
